How to pull information from output and turn into dataframe
I am building lots of logistic regression models, and I need to somehow export the OR, CI, and p-values plus the covariate/level information.
I have been able to get the OR, CI, and p-values into a dataframe, but the labels for the levels/variables are lost in the export.
#packages
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("AER")
library("AER")
library(writexl)

#data
data(Affairs, package="AER")
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs >  0] <- 1
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs == 0] <- 0

# logistic regression model
model <- glm(ynaffair~gender + age + yearsmarried + children + religiousness + education + occupation + rating,
               family = binomial,
             data = Affairs)
summary(model)

#formatting the output
 model_output <- as.data.frame(cbind(round(exp(model$coefficients), 2), 
                     exp(confint.default(model)),
                     summary(model)$coefficients[,4]))  %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 3)   %>% 
  unite(CI, c(`2.5 %`, `97.5 %`), sep = ", ", remove = TRUE)

# Exporting it to Excel
 write_xlsx(model_output, "model_output.xlsx")

Output as dataframe:

Excel output:

What I want it to look like:

What is the best way to get the output information into a dataframe and into Excel?

Have a look at the broom package, which has options to extract model information in a tidy (i.e. data frame) way, from where you can easily export to Excel.

I have not, I will look into it. Thanks!

dummy.coef(model) will give the coefficients for all levels for each factor.

It looks like the information you want to keep are row names of your data.frame.  Convert them into a proper column before saving the xlsx file.  One way is
model_output |>
  as_tibble(rownames = "my_new_name") |>
  write_xlsx("model_output.xlsx")

If you can't think of any better name than my_new_name, then you could use a space rownames = " "
